# $L^2$ but not $L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

In R where dimensions $d=1$? I know that if $s \ge 0.5$, then $H^s$ is in $L^{\infty}$. So we can find a function that is in $L^2$ but not in $L^{\infty}$. I would like an example for such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x}}$ is in $L^2((0,1))$ but not $L^\infty((0,1)).$

Comment: Close...but not quite.

Comment: @Ian whoops. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is in $L^1$. Is it better now?

Comment: what you want is $1/x^{1/4}\cdot \chi_{(0,1)}(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Another example: $|\ln |x||^{1/2} \in L^2((0,1)) \setminus L^\infty((0,1))$